# What timestamp will be changed when I rename a file on UNIX

Tags: unix

Or any other suggestions, I just want to check whether a file was renamed at a given time.

Comment: Use `ls -l` in the folder of the renamed file & look for the time you expect it was renamed.

Comment: But I found that mv doesn't change the last modified time.

Comment: Ah yes, `mv` does not affect the timestamp as per POSIX rules. If you use `cp` instead, it would affect the timestamp.

Comment: Yep, if I renamed a file, can I just find some clues about this operation later.

Comment: Check the mod time of the parent directory, maybe? A move or rename doesn't actually affect the file, it affects the directory containing it.

Answer (score 2):

When you rename a file, out of its MAC times only the C (change) time changes:

```
[luke@ll test]$ touch file_time
[luke@ll test]$ stat file_time 
  File: 'file_time'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 33845249    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    luke)   Gid: ( 1000/    luke)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2018-01-30 18:09:48.157529527 +0100
Modify: 2018-01-30 18:09:48.157529527 +0100
Change: 2018-01-30 18:09:48.157529527 +0100
 Birth: -
[luke@ll test]$ mv -iv file_time file_time2
'file_time' -> 'file_time2'
[luke@ll test]$ stat file_time2 
  File: 'file_time2'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 33845249    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    luke)   Gid: ( 1000/    luke)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2018-01-30 18:09:48.157529527 +0100
Modify: 2018-01-30 18:09:48.157529527 +0100
Change: 2018-01-30 18:09:58.033633333 +0100
 Birth: -
```

---

Answer (score 1):

After you `mv` the file to its new name, `touch` the file. This will change the time stamp. As an example, I created 3 files `a`, `b`, and `c` (via `touch a b c`)

```
23:11:50 --> ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 c
23:11:52 --> mv a aa
23:12:18 --> ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 aa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 c
23:12:21 --> touch aa
23:12:47 --> ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:12 aa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 b
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kkanos kkanos 0 Oct  3 23:11 c
```

Clearly `a` was `mv`'d to `aa` with the original time stamp, then `touch`'d to get the new time stamp.